# git svn rebase not working but git svn fetch does

Tags: git, git-svn

I'm having an issue where when I run

```
git svn rebase
```

or

```
git svn rebase -l
```

nothing happens. However,

```
git svn fetch
```

brings down new revisions successfully. This started happening when I used 'gitk' to revert my working copy to a previous revision, then accidentally ran "git reset --hard HEAD" without switching back over to my master branch. Any ideas on how to fix this without re-cloning?

***EDIT***

'git status' output

```
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       several untracked files
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

'git branch -avv' shows all of my local and remote branches available to me. There is a lot of output, so what exactly should I be looking for?

It is worthy to note that I can fetch new revisions from another branch, it seems that my master branch is what is screwed up.

Comment: What you did should not have the effect you describe. How exactly did you "revert to a previous revision"? Also, please post the output of `git branch -avv` and `git status`.

Comment: I used gitk to "Reset master branch to here" on a selected commit, then ran "git reset --hard HEAD" by mistake instead of checking out the HEAD commit.

Comment: Please read my comment and post the output of the commands.

Comment: Did you accidentally reset your `master`'s upstream? Try `git branch -u master remotes/trunk` or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when my company was migrating the SVN server to a different domain. After I updated the URL in the repo config with `git config --edit`, `git svn fetch` worked but `git svn rebase` didn't do anything and had to be closed with Ctrl+C. (The SVN server was temporarily accessible at both domains.)

My solution was to edit the repo config again to use the old URL, then run `git svn rebase`, then edit the repo config a third time to use the new URL. After that, running `git svn rebase` with the new URL worked fine.

I don't know *why* it worked, but it did. Maybe this will help someone in the same situation.